# JTextArea wont ".paint" to the correct location on screen

Tags: java, jtextarea

Im having a problem with JTextArea that has been quite annoying.

I am trying to make a 2D game for a project, and I am currently attempting to put text on my screen using JTextArea instead of just images.

My code for configuring the JTextArea is as follows:

```
    Insets margin = new Insets(10,30,0,0); //bottom, left, top, right

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setSize(textWidth, textHeight);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setMargin(margin);
    textArea.setFont(halFont);
    textArea.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    textArea.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    textArea.setLocation(0, 600);
```

My problem is that when I "paint" it to the screen using:
`textArea.paint(g);`
It just paints to the position 0,0 however it keeps the rest of the textArea formatting including color, insets, font, etc.

When I run `textArea.getLocation();` after painting, it claims it is at the position 0,600 even though its clearly at 0,0.

I have tried changing the x and y position calues, but the text still stays at 0,0 on my screen. Because of this i'm fairly certain that it is something to do with the `.paint` call rather than `.setLocation` call.

I realize that I should be using a format manager of some sort, but since i'm using `.paint` I get the feeling it won't help.

Q: How can I use the `.paint` call and change the position of the text being painted to the screen.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't think you understand how painting works in Java. You should never call textArea.paint(g); directly (unless the g is a graphics object from an Image) Instead, you should call textArea.repaint()

Comment: So what does the textArea.repaint() do exactly (sorry XD). I have just done everything with g.paint thus far and it works perfectly. When I try using .repaint by itself, the text no longer appears at all, so I'm confused on when I should be using it

Comment: Using the power of terrible programming I was able to put my text in the desired position by increasing the Height of JTextArea to my screen's height, then I used insets instead of .setLocation :3

Comment: just a grain of advice: Assuming your a student or otherwise not programming this in a professional capacity, it is better to learn how to do it right rather than settling on "terrible programming"

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Layout managers, the layout manager itself is the one that calls `setLocation`, and `setSize`, so any attempt you make will be overwritten. You need to use the layout manager and allow it to place the component where it thinks it should go. You influence its position by

```
1) what layoutmanager you choose
2) your use of setPreferredSize(Dimension d), setMinimumSize(Dimension d), setMaximumSize(Dimension d)
```